# How to force or "hint" that an Entity field should be indexed in yaml?

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-orm, yaml

Is there any way in Doctrine 2 to hint that a column should be indexed when the database is automatically generated? I've got a Thread Entity:

```
Entities\Thread:
  type: entity
  table: Thread
  repositoryClass: Repositories\ThreadRepository
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
  fields:
    type:
      type: enumthreadtype
    code:
      type: string
      length: 10
      nullable: true
  manyToOne:
    group:
      targetEntity: Group
      inversedBy: threads
  oneToMany:
    messages:
      targetEntity: Message
      mappedBy: thread
    attachments:
      targetEntity: ThreadAttachment
      mappedBy: thread
```

Threads are often searched for by their "code" - a 10-character random string - rather than their id. Is there any way to indicate that an index should be created using yaml, or do I simply need to do this in my database after the table is created?

Answer (score 1):

I could not find the documentation for this in yaml, but after reading `Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadatainfo` I worked out that it is as follows

If you wanted to index your code field your yaml mapping would be

```
Entities\Thread:
  type: entity
  table: Thread
  indexes:
      # _idx as suffix...
      thread_code_idx:
          columns: [ code ]
      # We can specify multiple indexes 
      another_idx
          # we can specify multiple columns for compound indexes
          columns [ type, code ] 
  repositoryClass: Repositories\ThreadRepository
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
  fields:
    type:
      type: enumthreadtype
    code:
      type: string
      length: 10
      nullable: true
  manyToOne:
    group:
      targetEntity: Group
      inversedBy: threads
  oneToMany:
    messages:
      targetEntity: Message
      mappedBy: thread
    attachments:
      targetEntity: ThreadAttachment
      mappedBy: thread
```